# WebRTC- Recording multiple audio and video streams or Screen Recording with audio

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc, audio-recording, screen-recording

I am working on a PHP project. I want to integrate WEBRTC Video Conferencing, which is done but I even want an option for all the attendees to record the conference ,both audio and video.I know that there are some issues with recording multiple audio streams in chrome and IE.So is there any alternative? Can we capture the screen with audio(i.e capturing both the mic and speakers), just like "one note" is used in skype? if yes, then how? Please suggest something?